# how to create folder and upload images in ipfs

Tags: ipfs

**https://proto.school/#/mutable-file-system 

I have gone through this link but don’t know how to do same thing in node.js**


I have added 'hello' word into the IPFS network and its working fine and also i have used image to upload into ipfs but i want to know how can i create folder in ipfs network and upload images into that folder

So my problem is that how to create the folder and upload picture into that folder.

Here is my code.

```
     const addFile = async () => {
            //const Added = await ipfs.add('hello');
              const fsReadImgData = fs.readFileSync('image1.jpg');
               var ipfsSave = await ipfs.add({ 
                                    path:image1.jpg, 
                                    content: fsReadImgData 
                              });
            return fsReadImgData;
        }
        const fileHash = await addFile();
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer without seeing the form code, as it determines what the contents of request will be. Once you know what the contents of the request are, you can then add a file using the method in the link you shared. Here is the documentation for MFS file adding - note that the accepted content types are String, Buffer, AsyncIterable<Buffer> or Blob.  https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsfileswritepath-content-options

Comment: Also you can dump the contents of the Request object and inspect it to find out what part of that variable is the contents of the uploaded file, and which type it is.

Comment: i just need the code for creating folder into ipfs network and the code to upload images into that folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read file into a buffer (or replace with however you're getting the image data:

```
const imgdata = fs.readFileSync('/yourfile.jpg');
```

Regular IPFS files method (immutable, you do not expect to update these):

```
let added = await ipfs.add({
  path: 'images/yourfile.jpg',
  content: imgdata
}, { wrapWithDirectory: true })
```

Mutable filesystem method (you expect to update and change the files):

```
await ipfs.files.mkdir('/images')

await ipfs.files.write(
  '/images/yourfile.jpg',
  imgdata,
  {create: true})
```